# Handling heterogeneous paths in a set

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory

I have two heterogeneous paths in a `Set`, with the same endpoints but over different
paths. How do I fill in between them?

In more concrete terms, here's my code with `foo` being my question:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}

module _ where

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Cubical.Foundations.Everything hiding (assoc)

variable
  ℓ : Level
  A : Type ℓ
  B : A → Type ℓ
  x y : A

module _
  (AIsSet : isSet A)
  (p q : Path A x y)
  (BIsProp : ∀ x → isProp (B x))
  {x′ : B x}
  {y′ : B y}
  where

  p′ : PathP (λ i → B (p i)) x′ y′
  p′ = isProp→PathP BIsProp p x′ y′

  q′ : PathP (λ i → B (q i)) x′ y′
  q′ = isProp→PathP BIsProp q x′ y′

  foo : PathP (λ i → PathP (λ j → B (AIsSet x y p q i j)) x′ y′) p′ q′
  foo = ?
    where
      doesThisHelp? : ∀ j → PathP (λ i → B (AIsSet x y p q i j)) (p′ j) (q′ j)
      doesThisHelp? j = isProp→PathP BIsProp (λ i → AIsSet x y p q i j) (p′ j) (q′ j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is when you want to use `isOfHLevel→isOfHLevelDep`:

```
  foo : PathP (λ i → PathP (λ j → B (AIsSet x y p q i j)) x′ y′) p′ q′
  foo = let r = isOfHLevel→isOfHLevelDep {n = 2} (\ a → hLevelSuc 1 (B a) (BIsProp a)) in
        r x′ y′ p′ q′ (AIsSet x y p q)
```

`doesThisHelp?` probably does not, as it is building a square where two of the sides are `p'` and `q'` but you don't know what the other two sides are. While `foo` specifies the other two sides to be (constantly) `x'` and `y'`.